# Postgresql Syntax Error for Trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, syntax-error

here is my Trigger and when i try to execute this I am getting error

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vqm_minoutline_cp_trg()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$ DECLARE 
   --TYPE RECORD IS REFCURSOR;
  Cur_Defaults                RECORD;
  v_M_Product_ID              VARCHAR(32); --OBTG:varchar2--
  v_VQM_Parameter_ID          VARCHAR(32); --OBTG:varchar2--
  vqm_minoutline_parameter_id    VARCHAR(32);
  v_count             NUMERIC;
BEGIN

    IF AD_isTriggerEnabled()='N' THEN IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN RETURN OLD; ELSE RETURN NEW; END IF; 
    END IF;

    --  Default Quality Parameter for Product
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN

    FOR Cur_Defaults IN
(
    SELECT VQM_Parameter_ID, Description, Criteria, MinValue, MaxValue, TextValue
        FROM  VQM_Product_Parameter VPP
    WHERE VPP.M_PRODUCT_ID=new.M_PRODUCT_ID

)
LOOP
    /*
        Creating quality lines for Purchase Order Line
    */

     SELECT * INTO  vqm_minoutline_parameter_id FROM Ad_Sequence_Next('vqm_minoutline_parameter', Cur_Defaults.VQM_Parameter_ID);

          INSERT INTO vqm_minoutline_parameter    //here line 65 and so on
          (vqm_minoutline_parameter_id, m_inoutline_id, VQM_PARAMETER_ID, AD_Client_ID, AD_Org_ID, 
          IsActive, Created, CreatedBy, Updated, UpdatedBy, Criteria, MaxValue, MinValue, 
          TextValue, Description)
          VALUES
          (vqm_minoutline_parameter_id, new.m_inoutline_id, Cur_Defaults.VQM_PARAMETER_ID, 
          new.AD_Client_ID, new.AD_Org_ID, 'Y', TO_DATE(NOW()), new.CreatedBy, TO_DATE(NOW()), new.UpdatedBy,
          Cur_Defaults.Criteria, Cur_Defaults.MaxValue, Cur_Defaults.MinValue, Cur_Defaults.TextValue, 
          Cur_Defaults.Description);

END LOOP;


ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN

    IF new.M_PRODUCT_ID != old.M_PRODUCT_ID THEN

        DELETE FROM vqm_minoutline_parameter WHERE m_inoutline_id = new.m_inoutline_id;

        FOR Cur_Defaults IN
        (
        SELECT VQM_Parameter_ID, Description, Criteria, MinValue, MaxValue, TextValue
        FROM  VQM_Product_Parameter VPP
        WHERE VPP.M_PRODUCT_ID=new.M_PRODUCT_ID
        )
        LOOP
        /*
        Creating quality lines for Purchase Order Line
        */

        SELECT * INTO  vqm_minoutline_parameter_id FROM Ad_Sequence_Next('vqm_minoutline_parameter', Cur_Defaults.VQM_Parameter_ID);

        INSERT INTO vqm_minoutline_parameter
        (
        vqm_minoutline_parameter_id, m_inoutline_id, VQM_PARAMETER_ID, AD_Client_ID, AD_Org_ID, 
        IsActive, Created, CreatedBy, Updated, UpdatedBy, Criteria, MaxValue, MinValue, 
        TextValue, Description
        )

        VALUES
        (
        vqm_minoutline_parameter_id, new.m_inoutline_id, Cur_Defaults.VQM_PARAMETER_ID, 
        new.AD_Client_ID, new.AD_Org_ID, 'Y', TO_DATE(NOW()), new.CreatedBy, TO_DATE(NOW()), new.UpdatedBy,
        Cur_Defaults.Criteria, Cur_Defaults.MaxValue, Cur_Defaults.MinValue, Cur_Defaults.TextValue, 
        Cur_Defaults.Description
        );

        END LOOP;

    END IF; 

END IF;

    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN RETURN OLD; ELSE RETURN NEW; END IF; 

END 

; $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION vqm_minoutline_cp_trg()
  OWNER TO saksham27;
```

This is error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO vqm_minoutline_parameter ( $1 , m_inoutline_id, ...
                                           ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO vqm_minoutline_parameter ( $1 , m_inoutline_id, VQM_PARAMETER_ID, AD_Client_ID, AD_Org_ID, IsActive, Created, CreatedBy, Updated, UpdatedBy, Criteria, MaxValue, MinValue, TextValue, Description) VALUES ( $1 ,  $2 ,  $3 ,  $4 ,  $5 , 'Y', TO_DATE(NOW()),  $6 , TO_DATE(NOW()),  $7 ,  $8 ,  $9 ,  $10 ,  $11 ,  $12 )
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "vqm_minoutline_cp_trg" near line 66


********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
SQL state: 42601
Context: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "vqm_minoutline_cp_trg" near line 66
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this query:

```
  INSERT INTO vqm_minoutline_parameter    //here line 65 and so on
  (vqm_minoutline_parameter_id, m_inoutline_id, VQM_PARAMETER_ID, AD_Client_ID, AD_Org_ID, 
  IsActive, Created, CreatedBy, Updated, UpdatedBy, Criteria, MaxValue, MinValue, 
  TextValue, Description)
  VALUES
  (vqm_minoutline_parameter_id, new.m_inoutline_id, Cur_Defaults.VQM_PARAMETER_ID, 
  new.AD_Client_ID, new.AD_Org_ID, 'Y', TO_DATE(NOW()), new.CreatedBy, TO_DATE(NOW()), new.UpdatedBy,
  Cur_Defaults.Criteria, Cur_Defaults.MaxValue, Cur_Defaults.MinValue, Cur_Defaults.TextValue, 
  Cur_Defaults.Description);
```

You're using `vqm_minoutline_parameter_id` both as a column name and a plpgsql variable name. As a result, plpgsql replaces the column name with `$1` which leads to an incorrect query.

The workaround is to change the variable name to something that does not clash with any column name.

The documentation mentions the problem in [Variable Substitution](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST), with this note:

> Note: PostgreSQL versions before 9.0 would try to substitute the
>   variable in all three cases, leading to syntax errors.

Presumably you're using a pre-9.0 version otherwise the error wouldn't occur. In theory column names are no longer substituted with more recent versions.